# Create a new column with the minimum of other columns on same row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following DataFrame

Input:

```
A    B    C    D    E
2    3    4    5    6
1    1    2    3    2 
2    3    4    5    6
```

I want to add a new column that has the minimum of A, B and C for that row

Output:

```
A    B    C    D    E    Goal
2    3    4    5    6    2
1    1    2    3    2    1 
2    3    4    5    6    2
```

I have tried to use

```
df = df[['A','B','C]].min()
```

but I get errors about hashing lists and also I think this will be the min of the whole column I only want the min of the row for those specific columns.

How can I best accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Use `min` along the columns with `axis=1`

Inline solution that produces copy that doesn't alter the original

```
df.assign(Goal=lambda d: d[['A', 'B', 'C']].min(1))

   A  B  C  D  E  Goal
0  2  3  4  5  6     2
1  1  1  2  3  2     1
2  2  3  4  5  6     2
```

---

#### Same answer put different

Add column to existing dataframe

```
new = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].min(axis=1)

df['Goal'] = new

df

   A  B  C  D  E  Goal
0  2  3  4  5  6     2
1  1  1  2  3  2     1
2  2  3  4  5  6     2
```

Answer (score 5):

Add `axis = 1` to your `min`

```
df['Goal'] = df[['A','B','C']].min(axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to define an axis across which you are applying the min function, which would be 1 (columns).

```
df['ABC_row_min'] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].min(axis = 1)
```